# the filter function is not correct?

Tags: reactjs

the filter function should return the complete list of members as long as the search input is empty, only the complete list is shown when the page is loaded but once I type letters or a name the name remains and when deleting letters or the complete name the complete list is not returned, but the first search remains.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getCollegiate } from '../../api/drupalAPI'
import {Collegiate} from '@icofcv/common';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import './CollegiateList.css';

export const CollegiateList = () => {

    const [collegiateList, setCollegiateList] = useState<Collegiate[]>([]);
    const [searchCollegiate, setSearchCollegiate] = useState("");
    console.log(searchCollegiate);
    
    const fetchCollegiateList = async () => {
        getCollegiate().then((response)=>{
            console.log(response)
            setCollegiateList(response);
        }).catch ( (error)  => {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        });
    }

    const handleChange=e=>{
        setSearchCollegiate(e.target.value);
        filter(e.target.value);
      }
      
      const filter=(termSearch)=>{
        var resultSearch= collegiateList.filter((element)=>{
          if(element.firstname.toString().toLowerCase().includes(termSearch.toLowerCase())
          || element.lastname.toString().toLowerCase().includes(termSearch.toLowerCase())
          ){
            return element;
          }
        });
        setCollegiateList(resultSearch);
      }
  

    useEffect (() => {
        fetchCollegiateList();  
    }, []);

    return(
            <>
                <div>
                    <Form className="d-flex">
                        <Form.Control
                        type="search"
                        value={searchCollegiate}
                        placeholder="Search"
                        className="me-2"
                        aria-label="Search"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        {/* <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button> */}
                    </Form>
              </div>
              <div className="content-collegiatelist">
                  <table>
                      <tbody>
                          <tr>
                              <th>Tipo</th>
                              <th>Colegiado</th>
                              <th>Nombre</th>
                              <th>Apellido</th>
                              <th>Provincia</th>
                          </tr>
                      
                      {
                          collegiateList.map((collegiate) => (
                            
                            <div className="content-table-td">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{collegiate.color}</td>
                                    <td>{collegiate.collegiate}</td>
                                    <td>{collegiate.firstname}</td>
                                    <td>{collegiate.lastname}</td>
                                    <td>{collegiate.provincia}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </div>
                      ))
                  }
                          
                      </tbody>
                  </table>
                  
              </div>
            </>  
    )
}
```

Comment: Because you have already overwritten the list array while searching so you won't get that, You need 2 state for this one with filter and other without filter applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is not the way you should use it, the filter function keep the element depending if the function returns a boolean or not, see below how you should do it

```
const searchFilter = (termSearch) => {
  setCollegiateList(prev => prev.filter(element => element.firstname.toString().toLowerCase().includes(termSearch.toLowerCase()) || element.lastname.toString().toLowerCase().includes(termSearch.toLowerCase())))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have already overwritten the list array while searching so you won't get that, You need 2 state for this one with filter and other without filter applied

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getCollegiate } from '../../api/drupalAPI'
import {Collegiate} from '@icofcv/common';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import './CollegiateList.css';

export const CollegiateList = () => {

    const [collegiateList, setCollegiateList] = useState<Collegiate[]>([]);
    const [collegiateListFiltered, setCollegiateListFiltered] = useState<Collegiate[]>([]);
    const [searchCollegiate, setSearchCollegiate] = useState("");
    console.log(searchCollegiate);
    
    const fetchCollegiateList = async () => {
        getCollegiate().then((response)=>{
            console.log(response)
            setCollegiateList(response);
            setCollegiateListFiltered(response)
        }).catch ( (error)  => {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        });
    }

    const handleChange=e=>{
        setSearchCollegiate(e.target.value);
        filter(e.target.value);
      }
      
      const filter=(termSearch)=>{
        var resultSearch= collegiateList.filter((element)=>{
          if(element.firstname.toString().toLowerCase().includes(termSearch.toLowerCase())
          || element.lastname.toString().toLowerCase().includes(termSearch.toLowerCase())
          ){
            return element;
          }
        });
        setCollegiateListFiltered(resultSearch);
      }
  

    useEffect (() => {
        fetchCollegiateList();  
    }, []);

    return(
            <>
                <div>
                    <Form className="d-flex">
                        <Form.Control
                        type="search"
                        value={searchCollegiate}
                        placeholder="Search"
                        className="me-2"
                        aria-label="Search"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        {/* <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button> */}
                    </Form>
              </div>
              <div className="content-collegiatelist">
                  <table>
                      <tbody>
                          <tr>
                              <th>Tipo</th>
                              <th>Colegiado</th>
                              <th>Nombre</th>
                              <th>Apellido</th>
                              <th>Provincia</th>
                          </tr>
                      
                      {
                          collegiateListFiltered.map((collegiate) => (
                            
                            <div className="content-table-td">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{collegiate.color}</td>
                                    <td>{collegiate.collegiate}</td>
                                    <td>{collegiate.firstname}</td>
                                    <td>{collegiate.lastname}</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

Where do you store your full list? Looks like you override your list `collegiateList` with every call of filter function? And where you check empty string for filtering?

Also you can call `useEffect` depends on `[searchCollegiate]` and do filter inside callback function

Comment: And why I get minus, if I found root of the problem..? I just can't ask question in comments cause of my reputation under 50...